# How to compile TeX ---> HTML use TeX4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html, winedt

I have problem compile TeX ---> HTML use TeX4ht and my MWE like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[html]{tex4ht}
\title{Simulation of Energy Loss Straggling}
\author{Maria Physicist}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Landau theory}
\label{sec:phys332-l}
Integral Riemann-Stieltjes menyisakan topik yang menarik. Didalam paper ini kita akan menyelidiki modifikasi integral Riemann yang didefinisikan pada sebarang himpunan. Kasus khusus integral ini kali pertama didefinisikan oleh Coppin dan Vance dimana integralnya didefinisikan atas dense subset interval yang memuat titik-titik ujung interval itu. Coppin dan Vance telah menunjukkan syarat perlu dan cukup untuk $f$ terintegral $g$ pada dense subset dari $[a,b]$ dimana $f{\mid}_M$ dan ${\mid}_M$ tidak mempunyai persekutuan titik kontinu. Vance memberikan karakterisasi fungsional terbatas. Dia telah membuktikan representasi teorema untuk fungsi quasi kontinu didefinisikan pada selang tertutup. Misalkan $\Delta$ didefinisikan himpunan semua dense subset dari $[a,b]$ yang memuat $a$ dan $b$. Coppin memberikan syarat dimana $f$ terintegral $g$ pada $M'$ di $\Delta$ dibuktikan $f$ terintegral $g$ di $M$ di $\Delta$ dan $M\subset M'$. Dia menunjukkan bahwa jika $f$ terintegral $g$ pada suatu anggota uncountable $\Delta$, maka $f$ teintegral $g$ pada banyak uncountable $\Delta$. Tambahan, Dia telah membuktikan bahwa  jika $M$ anggota countable $M$ dari $\Delta$, maka ada fungsi bernilai real  $f$ dan $g$ dengan daerah asal $[a,b]$ dengan demikian bahwa $f$ terintegral $g$ pada $M$ dan tidak ada anggota $\Delta$ lainnya. Coppin menambahkan hasilnya dengan menunjukkan bahwa $f$ terintegral $g$ pada $M$ di $\Delta$ dan $f{\mid}_M$ dan $g{\mid}_M$ yang tidak mempunyai titik persekutuan yang diskontinu jika dan hanya jika $f$ terintegral pada setiap himpunan bagian $M \in \Delta$ juga terbukti bahwa jika $M \in \Delta$, $f$ dan $g$ fungsi yang didefinisikan pada $[a,b]$ yang mempunyai persekutuan dari kanan(kiri) di $z$ dan $f$ terintegral $g$ pada $M$, maka $f$ terintegral pada $M\cup \{z\}$ dan $\int_{M\cup \{z\}}f dg=\int_{M}f dg$ yang menunjukkan bahwa jika $f$ dan $g$ fungsi dengan daerah asal $[a,b]$ dan $f$ dan $g$ tidak mempunyai titik persekutuan yang kontinu dari kiri(kanan), maka himpunan $\{w:w=\int_{M} f dg \bigvee M \in \Delta \}$ terhubung.\\
Di paper ini, kita akan belajar integral Siteltjes atas sebarang himpunan. Kita akan membandingkan integral ini dengan partisi penghalus integral Stieltjes.
\section{Definisi Permulaan}
Kita akan memberikan definisi dan penetapan yang digunakan di paper ini. \\
Secara umum, selang $M$ adalah himpunan ${[a,b]_M}=[c,d]\cap M$ dimana $c,d \in M$ dan $c<d$. Dua interval dikatakan nonovelapping jika dan hanya jika $A\cap B$ tidak memuat selang. Koleksi interval tak kosong dikatakan nonoverlapping jika dan hanya jika setiap dua anggota yang berbeda adalah nonoverlapping. Di paper ini, semua fungsinya terbatas.
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{bib-LAND}
L.Landau.
On the Energy Loss of Fast Particles by Ionisation.
Originally published in \emph{J. Phys.}, 8:201, 1944.
Reprinted in D.ter Haar, Editor, \emph{L.D.Landau, Collected
papers}, page 417. Pergamon Press, Oxford, 1965.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

And the Result like this :

[image: Blank Page]

I compile my document with WinEdt 8.0 (LaTeX --> Html) like this :

[image: LaTeXtoHTML]

How to fix produce LaTeX to HMTL document ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command "LaTeX -> HTML" in WinEdt 8.0 runs `htlatex.exe` with the command line

```
htlatex.exe "<filename>.tex" "html,fn-in,imgdir:Images/," "" "<filename>" "--interaction=nonstopmode"
```

If you want your document to be compiled fine, simply comment out the line

```
\usepackage[html]{tex4ht}
```

and you will get the following result ("Accessories" -> "HTML Preview"):

[image]

Comment: i will try your solution but i get the answer my problem  with compile to dvi and then compile LaTeX --> HTML :)

Comment: @HirWanto I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: ok , your answer is perfect.

Comment: karkoeller, any question again , what is the difference TeX4ht and LaTeX2HTML ?

Comment: @HirWanto They are two different programs that attempt to compile TeX sources into HTML files. The command you've used in WinEdt runs TeX4ht (`htlatex.exe`). Info: [LaTeX2HTML](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2html) and [TeX4ht](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht).

Comment: karkoeller, ok.